An isomorphism between $\langle A,B\rangle$ and $\langle a,b: bab^{-1} = a^{-1}, a^n=b^2\rangle$.
In the comments of another question there was mention of this isomorphism, but it wasn't proven. I tried proving it but I couldn't even convince myself it was true in the first place. I suppose it's supposed to be easy, but I do not understand.
$\langle \begin{bmatrix} e^{i\pi/n} & 0\\ 
 0&e^{-i\pi/n} \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0 \end{bmatrix} \rangle \cong \langle a,b: a^{2n} = e, b^4 = e, bab^{-1}=a^{-1}, a^n=b^2\rangle.$
To show the result we define a map from the left to the right and show it's an isomorphism. Let $\varphi(A) \rightarrow a$ and $\varphi(B) \rightarrow b$. To show it's a homomorphism we take an arbitrary $C = A^iB^j$ from the left hand side and note that $\varphi(C) = \varphi(A^iB^j) = \varphi(A^i)\varphi(B^j) = \varphi(A)^i\varphi(B)^j = a^ib^j.$ Now using the rules from the presentation we can reduce somehow?
We need to show the order of $A$ is $2n$, and the order of $B$ is $4$? This is enough to show our homomorphism is an isomorphism?

If we call the matrices on the left $A$ and $B$, then the isomorphism is defined by sending $A$ to $a$ and $B$ to $b$. Knowing that, can you say how it acts on an arbitrary element of the left-hand group? Can you show it's injective and bijective? You can show your work by clicking "Edit" just below your question. In general, we ask that folks show what they've tried and exactly where they're stuck, so ... write a little something, and we'll see how it goes from there.

Less some loose ends, try to prove that the matrices satisfy the relations.

Is there a reason you omitted some of the relations in the title?

First of all observe that your group $G(=G_n)$ has abelianization $\mathbb Z_4$ if $n$ is odd otherwise is $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ is $n$ is even.
This suggests that probably $G$ is a finite group. To prove this, it is sufficient to show that each element can be written as $a^ib^j$ for some $i,j$. I let you to prove this.
Since both $a$ and $b$ have finite order and each element can be written as $a^jb^j$, then $G$ has finite order too. In particular, it is not so difficult to see that
$$G_{2^k}=Q_{2^k}, \qquad G_{2k+1}=\mathbb Z_{2k+1} \rtimes_\varphi \mathbb Z_4, \ \ \varphi\colon \mathbb Z_4\to Aut(\mathbb Z_{2k+1}) \qquad and \qquad G_{2k}=\mathbb Z_k\rtimes_\varphi Q_8,\ \ k\equiv 1 \  mod \ 2$$
Coming back to our problem, just define the map from the free group of two elements $\langle a ,b\rangle$ into the matrix group, where the pair $a$ and $b$ is going to  the pair of matrices respectively.  The map is a well defined homomorphism, and it is surjective by definition. Furthermore, the pair of matrices satisfy the relations of $G_n$, so that the map extends to the group $G_n$ into the matrix group. However, by construction this map is surjective and both the groups are finite, so the map is injective too. This proves that it is an isomorphism.

The homomorphism needs to be defined the other way round, into the matrix group and from the free group with relations. Otherwise you will run into problems showing that it exists.

Yeah you're right, thank you :). I corrected.
